# Samsung Earphone for iPad mini4

Tags: headphones

I am having iPad mini 4 . As everyone knows that it comes without earphone. Can I use my Samsung S5 earphone for the iPad? Please suggest me either I have to purchage only Apple earphone only? Thanks

Comment: Did you plug them in and try?  Are they just standard 3.5 mm headphones?

Comment: I didn't tried ...but they are 3.5mm..I didn't tried because of I thought they may give some problem

Comment: "Problem"? Like your iPad exploding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, headphones are headphones and the audio jack is standardized (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)) for more details).

Comment: Ok so I can use without any problem?

Comment: That's what standards are all about :-)